# how to enable bluetooth again after disabling?

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

I need to disable the `Bluetooth` and the enable it again. I disable that at this way:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
mBluetoothAdapter.disable(); 
}
```

but I can not enable that again at this way(nothing happen after running this code):

```
mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
```

why?

Comment: As this involves tinkering with actual hardware, I think you have to wait a bit before being able to enable it. You could try and see with `Thread.sleep(500)` or `1000` before enabling...

Comment: or cleaner: check if it is disabled and there for can be enabled

Comment: Now why did this question get a close vote for `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.`? This question seems appropriate in all aspects, even has code, attempted solution... Also, why the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this involves tinkering with actual hardware, I think you have to wait a bit before being able to enable it. You could try and see with `Thread.sleep(500)` or `1000` before enabling...

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    mBluetoothAdapter.disable(); 
    Thread.sleep(500); //code for dealing with InterruptedException not shown
    mBluetoothAdapter.enable(); 
}
```

However, this is flaky, having *magic numbers* resolve issues related to *events of a hardware device* is not nice. Not guarranteed to have well defined behaviour under all circumstances (different devices, different situations, etc...)

If the adapter reports disabled state only when it has been fully disabled, you could try something along these lines:

```
int retry=0;
while(retry++<5) {
     if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        mBluetoothAdapter.enable(); 
     }
     Thread.sleep(100); //again, InterruptedException handling not shown
}

if(retry==5) {
    //Ooops, still not successful. Handle situation here.
}
```

So in words: smaller delay, but a few retries, and check if it has been disabled or not.

Comment: thanks dude ! solved the problem, about 4 seconds was needed before enabling on my device (HTC Desire HD)

Comment: Wow, 4 seconds is awful long, I was thinking even the 500ms will be an overkill. Good to know it takes so long... Be sure to do it the 2nd way, different devices will have different properties...

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you transfer data via Bluetooth Socket. One socket - use 1 port. You can enable\disable bluetooth whlie all sockets ports(around 30) not be filled. So a question - how to get around of this problem, so a answer - keep track of close\open sockets. May be it helps.